# Notation about the Minkowski's functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading about the Minkowski's Functional and I stepped on this definition:

$$
p(x) = \inf \{ \lambda \in \Bbb R_{ > 0}: x \in \lambda K \}
$$

Does anyone knows what's the meaning of $\Bbb R_{>0}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_{>0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0 \} = \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: That's it? Thanks a lot man!